# Force Excel to accept a number as a list name

Tags: excel, list, validation

I'm trying to force Excel to accept the number '5' (for example) as the name of a list. The number is the serial number of a product, and I am trying to use lists and validation to offer drop-down menus.

I have sorted everything else, except for getting Excel to accept the name of the list as being a number with no text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a name has to start with a letter or an underscore. So what you want is not allowed by Excel by definition. You cannot force it.

Start all these serial number range names with an underscore as an alternative logic so you will not have this problem and dont have to single out numerical cases as the one you show

Comment: So as to keep the number as a number in my main sheet, I've created a table and used VLOOKUP to change a _5 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

Can you format a cell as text, enter the number and refer the Name of the List to that Cell?